# Using both XNA and WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, xna, window

I want to create a physic bodies redactor with XNA and BEPU.
I need to create a "window" with XNA, that will be actual working space, and another with form controls like buttons, lists etc. to select options like add shape, create constraint...
It also can be like 3dmax layout or Photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1

From the description:

> This sample shows you how to use an XNA Framework GraphicsDevice object to display 3D graphics inside a WinForms application.